# check if first two letter (digits) in a ip adress is '41' with PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex

I use PHP:s ['REMOTE_ADDR'] to fetch the users ip.

I want to see if that ip starts with a 41.

```
$usr_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Then I want to match, and if it starts with 41, then **die()**

I don't know how to do the matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr...

```
if (substr($usr_ip, 0, 2) == "41") {
    die('Access denied');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,2)=="41") die();
```

regex is overkill here

Answer (score 0):

```
if(substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, 2) == '41') die();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [substr](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)()?